# How do I determine my cell's height without explicitly setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth on its labels?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, uikit

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that fills my `UITableView`. It's a simple subclass with just a variable length `UILabel` in it, and I want to resize the cell based on the length of this label. In my Storyboard I have constraints set up that pin the label 15pt away from the edges of the cell's contentView.

However, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, it keeps giving me the incorrect height unless I specify the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` value for the `UILabel`. This seems unnecessary, as it can be determined based on the constraints I've set on the label. Intuitively, it's the width of the cell - 30 (15pt from each side) but that shouldn't have to be set explicitly, especially because I may change it to say, 20, later.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! MyTableViewCell
    let str = strangs[indexPath.row]
    cell.myLabel.text = str

    // If the following line is not included it does NOT return the right height
    // cell.myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.bounds.width - 30

    return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height + 1
}
```

How do I call `systemLayoutFittingSize:` to calculate the height of my cell without explicitly setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the label?